# Random image with text when refresh

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random, text

I am a java script beginner and I am trying to design a web page that shows two random numbers when refresh. According to these numbers a specific text should appear.

The numbers are images between 0 - 5.

as far, I wrote this code and it worked to change the images when refresh

```
var images1= new Array ("images/0.png","images/1.png","images/2.png","images/3.png",
"images/4.png","images/5.png");

var images2= new Array ("images/1.png","images/5.png","images/0.png","images/3.png",
"images/4.png","images/2.png");

function RandomImg() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * images1.length);
  var img1= document.getElementById('image1');

  img1.src = images1[x];
  var img2= document.getElementById('image2');
  img2.src = images2[x];
}
RandomImg();
```

after that, according to the images appear, if the first number in the image is bigger than the second, a text should appear and and vice versa.

So my questions are "Is it possible to link each image to a number then execute if statement? or am i going in the wrong direction regarding this ? and how is possible to do that ?"

I did a lot of research but didn't reach anything clear since a week :(

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, it is possible. You can use map in JavaScript to make a key value pair.
> Just study about map and implement it.
>
> [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i'll check it out :)